# How to Change the background of input type time active blue background

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
 <div className=" ">
         <input
              type="time"
              className="w-full h-full border-none outline-none"
          />
  </div>
```

I am using the input time field and I want to change the blue background. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short words, you can't. That's something that varies among browsers. The recommendation would be to build one from scratch with JavaScript, or accept it and build around it.

There are a few styles you can change though, just nothing from the pop-up.

```css
/* wrapper around time */
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper {}

/* space between the different fields */
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-text {}

/* hour field (us :focus to get rid of the default color on click) */
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-hour-field {}

/* minute field */
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-minute-field {}

/* AM/PM field */
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field {}

/* clear/reset button */
input[type=time]::-webkit-clear-button {}

/* up/down arrows */
input[type=time]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {}
```

Answer (score 1):

This not possible to change the inner style of input type date and time

Answer (score 0):

By the `className` attribute, I'm going to assume you're using TailwindCSS here.

You may want to consider using `hover:`

For example:

```
 <div>
        <input
              type="time"
              className="w-full h-full border-none outline-none hover:bg-blue-400 hover:duration-500 duration-500"
         />
 </div>
```

I'd strongly recommend checking out the [TailwindCSS Documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/utility-first) for more information and guidance.