# Formik Field type="time" change default color to custom color

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, datetimepicker

I have this time picker which I am using with Formik :

```
<Field
  type="time"
  name="end_time"
  disabled={editState}
  value={endTime}
  style={{ Width: "3vw" }}
  onChange={(e) => {
    setEndTime(e.target.value);
  }}
  className={
    "form-control" +
    (errors.end_time && touched.end_time ? " is-invalid" : "")
  }
/>
```

I want to change the default colour of hover and selected to a specific colour.
Is there any way to do this?

[The blue colour and black border or selection and hover as mentioned on this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5x5O.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74843699/how-to-change-the-background-of-input-type-time-active-blue-background

Comment: Add additional classes to the base one and ensure you are using a “reset css” if you want a uniform look between browsers

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Formik use Browser style, so you cannot customize it. (tested on chrome, edge & firefox and got differents styles)

Comment: A “reset css” would make the inputs appear more uniformly